# Why does my view only show 999 items?

Tags: drupal, view

I have a view in a very basic Drupal site -- its basic purpose is to collect data, not display it in any fancy way -- that will only show 999 items. I'm not referring to paging; I'm referring to the total number of items listed by the time you get to the last page, regardless of pagination size. I have looked at every item in the content type definition and the view and can't find anything that would cause this. I know it would be very weird, but is there some limit on the total number of items a Drupal view can handle? Is there some LIMIT 1000 clause attached to a SQL query somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind people -- the problem is that the field is a text field, and not numeric (as it should be), so the items are being sorted aphabetically and not as numbers. Oops.